# надо посчитать процент перелетов по маршруту к общему количеству перелетов. написал вот такой запрос:

Tags: postgresql

Надо посчитать процент перелетов по маршруту к общему количеству перелетов.

Написал вот такой запрос:

```
select distinct departure_airport, 
    arrival_airport, 
    count(flight_id) over (partition by (departure_airport, arrival_airport)), 
    count(flight_id) over (),
    round(count(flight_id) over (partition by (departure_airport, arrival_airport)) / count(flight_id) * 100, 3)
from flights f 
group by 1,2, flight_no, flight_id
```

но вместо процентов получаю значение количества перелетов по маршруту, т.е. деление не работает.

Подскажите, в чём причина?

Comment: Оконный COUNT() рассчитывается ПОСЛЕ группировки. А не во время..